# Trying to change a button image on a button press from another window in Java FX using FXML

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I am trying to make it a poker layout platform, where you can press a button and select which card you want and this card should then display on the button. Whenever I try to update the button imageview I get errors.

Here is my Java FX Code code

```java
@FXML
ImageView card1;

public void selectHeart2(ActionEvent Event) throws IOException{
    System.out.println("Selecting Card");
    ((Node)(Event.getSource())).getScene().getWindow().hide();
    Image image = new Image("file:images/hearts/hearts2.png");
    card1.setImage(image);
}
```

Here is my FXML

```xml
<AnchorPane minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="761.0" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.MainController">
   <children>
      <HBox layoutX="198.0" layoutY="190.0" prefHeight="95.0" prefWidth="412.0">
         <children>
            <Button maxHeight="120.0" maxWidth="90.0" minHeight="120.0" minWidth="90.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#selectCard1" prefHeight="120.0" prefWidth="90.0">
               <graphic>
                  <ImageView fx:id="card1" fitHeight="120.0" fitWidth="90.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" >

                  </ImageView>
               </graphic></Button>
```

and here is my error:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at application.MainController.selectHeart2(MainController.java:384)
    ... 55 more
```

the error (line 384) is: card1.setImage(image);

Answer (score 0):

edit: *wrong answer was here*. Keeping it temporarily to preserve useful comments.

Comment: Is that right? Surely `ImageView.setImage(null)` is OK (clears the image view), even if it's not what's intended. I think `card1` is null. Not enough information in the question to know, though.

Comment: I have this line inside my action: 
Image image = new Image("file:images/hearts/hearts2.png");

Is this not calling the image? if i change the url a bit and try other ways I get invalid URL Exceptions  @James_D

Comment: @call28c Exactly, that's what I'm saying. The image is loading fine, but `card1` is null. You haven't provided any way for anyone to know why that is, which is why I voted to close the question.

Comment: what do you require to figure out the issue then? @James_D

Comment: @call28c Since it seems clear that `card1` is null, and you presumably believe it should be initialized by the FXML loader, you should provide the evidence that causes you to believe that. I.e. convince us that this really is the controller for the FXML file you showed, and that `selectHeart2` is being invoked on the controller (and not on some other instance of the same class), etc etc. Preferably edit your question to include a [MCVE].

Comment: @James_D ouch, you are right. `card1` should be null -- maybe it was not initialized by FXML. @call28c, can you show us the rest of this exception stack -- who called `selectHeart2`?

Comment: @SergeyGrinev I have got rid of the errors now but nothing actually happens and the picture doesnt change. Im pretty sure im calling card1 with the "@FXMl ImageView card1;" line as it gets rid of a warning on the fxml saying that the id is not used.

Answer (score -2):

Try creating the card1 object prior to line 384. It will fix yhe NullPointerException error if I'm not mistaken.

card1=new ImageView();

Comment: Never initialize fields that are annotated `@FXML`.

Comment: this does get rid of the NullPointerException, but its not displaying the image on to the button